# Can somebody explain how this one hot encoder method works?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-processing

I have gotten this code online that one hot encodes an array of label encoded values. I particularly don't understand the last line. Please help

I initially thought that where ever y is 1, it replaces the value of that index with 1, but, how?

```
def read_dataset():
  df = pd.read_csv("sonar.all-data.csv")
  x = df[df.columns[0:60]].values
  y = df[df.columns[60]]
  encoder = LabelEncoder()
  encoder.fit(y)
  y = oneHotEncode(y)
  return(x, y)

def oneHotEncode(labels):
  n_labels = len(labels)
  n_unique_labels = len(np.unique(labels))
  oneHE = np.zeros((n_labels, n_unique_labels))
  oneHE[np.arange(n_labels), labels] = 1
  return oneHE
```

I am expecting to under how this code works but I don't understand that line with np.arange

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! It just create a list of index for the matrix to be filled with 1 on each row, on the column specified by label. However, not really the kind of the question expected on this site

Answer (score 0):

`np.arange()` is similar to `range()` but creates a numpy array. Hence, if you have 10 labels, it returns an array with the consecutive numbers from 0 to 9. This is used to choose the row of the `oneHE` array (that contains only zeros after initialization). The `labels` is used for choosing the columns.

So it's just selecting the respective column in all rows and setting the values to 1.